# TypeError when retrieving random digits

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a random three digit extension:

```
>>>  ''.join(str(x) for x in random.sample(range(1,10),3))
```

It works in the prompt. However, when I run the program, it raises a `TypeError: str object is not callable`. This is the line that I have:

```
    filename = hashlib.md5(imagefile.getvalue()).hexdigest() + 
              ''.join(str(x) for x in random.sample(range(1,10),3)) + '_thumb' + '.jpg'
```

What am I doing wrong here and how would I fix it?

Thank you for the help. I had invoked str previously in the code, which was causing the error:

```
str=""
for c in i.chunks(): 
    str += c
...
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what is giving you the error? It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried it out both in the console and calling it in a .py file and both work.

Are you sure you're not declaring a variable called "str" somewhere in your code before that invocation?

This works:

```
import random
filename= ''.join(str(x) for x in random.sample(range(1,10),3))
print filename
```

This:

```
import random
str = ''
filename= ''.join(str(x) for x in random.sample(range(1,10),3))
print filename
```

Give the same error you're reporting.

Answer (score 6):

You have replaced the global name `str`, which normally refers to the string type, with something else (most likely, a variable containing a string of little importance). Python does not generally treat these sorts of things as keywords (in Python 3.x, `True` and `False` have become keywords, where they were just global variables before).

That said, `random.sample` chooses non-repeating values, which doesn't seem like a requirement for the problem of "generate a random three digit extension". Neither does avoiding zeroes. I would just pick a single random number from 0-999 inclusive and format it appropriately ('%03d', or the equivalent in the new formatting).

Answer (score 3):

I would break up the statement into smaller pieces:

```
val=imagefile.getvalue()
m=hashlib.md5(val)
sample=random.sample(range(1,10),3)
r=''.join(str(x) for x in sample)
filename = '{m}{r}_thumb.jpg'.format(m=m.hexdigest(),r=r)
```

so that the traceback message will indicate which part is raising the exception.
A temporary print statement or use of a debugger will then narrow down problem further.

PS. Just a guess but the error would make sense if `random.sample` had been set to equal a `str`.

```
In [62]: random.sample='1'

In [63]: random.sample(range(1,10),3)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: What on earth for? The message is quite clear, and `str` only appears once in the code, so the culprit is already fingered.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: You are probably right that `str` has been overwritten, rather than `random.sample`. But you are misinterpreting the error message. It does not say that the builtin `str` has been overwritten, only that a `str` object is being called. Anything coming before paretheses is a possible culprit.

Comment: @Karl: what he's suggesting is perfectly valid possibility, though what you say is orders of magnitude more probable.

Comment: +1: splitting a big line into a number of smaller lines to find out more accurately where it's going wrong is a very useful technique for debugging.